# how to correctly deal with unwanted access from asp.net-mvc (mostly id part)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

let say I have this url:

```
http://myweb/item/info/1
```

with a link to

```
http://myweb/item/edit/1
```

and I don't want the user to manually change to

```
http://myweb/item/edit/2
```

I would want the user to click on the link from the info page so he can access the edit page.

how would you manage that?

Comment: Can you provide the reasoning you would want to do something like that?

Comment: @Justin, I don't want a user to just guess id and see information that he shouldn't be able to see or change... right now I like what sarcastic is saying

Comment: If I was using a website that, even though I had the authority to perform an action, required me to jump through hoops to do it, I'd be pissed off at the guy who wrote it.  Your requirements may be better served by moving what's on info/1 that is so super scary important for the user to see onto edit/1, or by implementing a wizard interface that exists on a single page and uses javascript for navigation, thus removing the ability to shortcut via the url (and the frustration of not being allowed to)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personally I wouldn't want to stop a user doing that; it's not terribly intuitive for a URL to work in one context and not in another.

Instead I would ensure that the user has permission to edit the item in question as part of the controller method for the 'edit' action and redirect to an error page if they do not.